# Iterate through column in Excel and marking it in a different cell

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript

I'm fairly new to JavaScript/TypeScript and I'm trying to to iterate through a column of my excel spreadsheet and if the cell contains the word "leave" have the output be text ("false negative") in a cell on the same row 8 columns over.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  // Get the current worksheet.
  let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();

  // Get the values of the used range.
  let range = selectedSheet.getUsedRange();
  let rangeValues = range.getValues();

  // Iterate over the Query column.
  let rowCount = range.getRowCount();
  for (let i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
    // Query is column "3" in the worksheet and indexed at 2.
    if (rangeValues[i][2].includes("leave")) {
      range.getCell(i, 10).setValue("false negative");
    }
  }
}
```

I get these errors

Line 13: rangeValues[i][2].includes is not a function

[13, 27] Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean'.
Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'number'.

Answer (score 0):

To make the minimal code changes to your code, you can construct a new String from the value.

```
String(rangeValues[i][2]).includes("leave")
```